# IF logic in jekyll markdown

Tags: markdown, jekyll, blogs

On my jekyll blog there is already a page that lists all the categories and all their respective posts, here is the code:

```
{% for category in site.categories %}
<div class="col-md-12 content-panel articles">
  <h2 id="{{ category | first }}-ref">{{ category | first }}</h2>
  <ul style="list-style: none;">
    {% for posts in category %}
      {% for post in posts %}
        <li>
          <!-- problem of for cycle can't use images <img src="/{{ post.header-img | prepend: site.baseurl }}" class="img-responsive" alt="{{ post.title }}"> -->
          <h3><a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
          <small class="hidden-xs">{{ post.date | date: "%B %-d, %Y" }}</small>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

  </ul>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

My question is, how can I show only the posts on `categoryX` for example?

I realize this is probably something simple but couldnt find anywhere how to, I tried changing `for posts in category` to `for posts in categoryX` but it didnt work

Comment: A repository url can help spot the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list a specific category you can specify it using `site.categories.CATEGORY` so it list all Posts in category CATEGORY.

For example, if you have a category called "diet" the you can filter its posts with `{% assign posts = site.categories.diet %}{% for post in posts %}`.. or `{% assign posts = site.category['diet'] %}`

Look at some of the Jekyll variables here: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/

Comment: Doesnt work, when I tried `{% for posts in site.categories.diet %}` it still shows nothing, even though on my post I used `categories: "diet"`

Comment: @leofontes  try {% assign posts = site.categories.diet %}{% for post in posts %}.. or {% assign posts = site.category['diet'] %}

Comment: Worked, thank you very much. If you can, edit your answer so that it displays what other people might need in the future (: